# Google protocol buffers huge in python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I started using the protocol buffer library, but noticed that it was using huge amounts of memory.  pympler.asizeof shows that a single one of my objects is about 76k!  Basically, it contains a few strings, some numbers, and some enums, and some optional lists of same.  If I were writing the same thing as a C-struct, I would expect it to be under a few hundred bytes, and indeed the ByteSize method returns 121 (the size of the serialized string).

Is that you expect from the library?  I had heard it was slow, but this is unusable and makes me more inclined to believe I'm misusing it.

**Edit**

Here is an example I constructed.  This is a pb file similar, but simpler than what I've been using

```
    package pb;

message A {
    required double a       = 1;
}

message B {
    required double b       = 1;
}

message C {
    required double c       = 1;
    optional string s       = 2;
}

message D {
    required string d       = 1;
    optional string e       = 2;
    required A a            = 3;
    optional B b            = 4;
    repeated C c            = 5;
}
```

And here I am using it

```
>>> import pb_pb2
>>> a = pb_pb2.D()
>>> a.d = "a"
>>> a.e = "e"
>>> a.a.a = 1
>>> a.b.b = 2
>>> c = a.c.add()
>>> c.c = 5
>>> c.s = "s"
>>> import pympler.asizeof
>>> pympler.asizeof.asizeof(a)
21440
>>> a.ByteSize()
42
```

I have version 2.2.0 of protobuf (a bit old at this point), and python 2.6.4.

Comment: Some demo code reproducing the behavior would be nice.

Comment: @phihag Here's something similar reproducing the behavior.

Answer (score 5):

Object instances have a bigger memory footprint in python than in compiled languages. For example, the following code, which creates very simple classes mimicking your proto displays 1440:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    self.a = 0.0

class B:
  def __init__(self):
    self.b = 0.0

class C:
  def __init__(self):
    self.c = 0.0
    self.s = ""

class D:
  def __init__(self):
    self.d = ""
    self.e = ""
    self.e_isset = 1
    self.a = A()
    self.b = B()
    self.b_isset = 1
    self.c = [C()]

d = D()
print asizeof(d)
```

I am not surprised that protobuf's generated classes take 20 times more memory, as they add a lot of boiler plate.

The C++ version surely doesn't suffer from this.

Comment: I wasn't expecting it to be small, but as you can see in this example, a really basic object is 20k!  That's a 500 fold increase over the size needed to hold the necessary information.  A factor of 10 is maybe ok, but 500 means you can't hold these more than a (relatively) small number of these objects in memory.  By contract, pympler suggests the size of an int is 24, which is maybe a 6-fold increase in size going from C++ to python.

Comment: if this is important you can try reduce size by using the `__slots__` class attribute.

Comment: I don't know any fundamental reason why `pb_pb2.D` needs to store actual Python objects. If it doesn't, this logic doesn't necessarily hold up. If it needn't and does, it sounds like it might be written poorly.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This isn't likely your actual issue here, but we've just been experiencing a 45MB protobuf message taking > 4GB ram when decoding.  It appears to be this: https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/156

which was known about in protobuf 2.6 and a fix was only merged onto master march 7 this year: https://github.com/google/protobuf/commit/f6d8c833845b90f61b95234cd090ec6e70058d06

Comment: Turns out the memory leak didn't fix our issue.